# Why is my R code only returning 1 output?

Tags: r, statistics

Hi I am new to using R and I am trying to create a version of Fermis Piano Tuner problem using it. however is it only returning 1 estimate when I need it to return 2 upon running the code. anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

```
{
Population<-(2695598)
PPH<-(2) 
HWTP<-(0.04) 
TPYPP<-(2) 
TPTPD<-(6) 
WPY<-(261) 
((Population/PPH)*HWTP*TPYPP/(TPTPD*WPY))


Population2<-(2679080)
PPH2<-(2.48) 
HWTP2<-(0.04) 
TPYPP2<-(2) 
TPTPD2<-(6) 
WPY2<-(261)

{((Population/PPH)*HWTP*TPYPP/(TPTPD*WPY))}
{((Population2/PPH2)*HWTP2*TPYPP2/(TPTPD2*WPY2))}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about changing last 2 lines into

```
c((Population/PPH)*HWTP*TPYPP/(TPTPD*WPY), 
  (Population2/PPH2)*HWTP2*TPYPP2/(TPTPD2*WPY2))
```

Answer (score 0):

### First, I suggest that you create a function

```
fermis_piano_tuner <-
  function(Population,PPH,HWTP,TPYPP,TPTPD,WPY){
    ((Population/PPH)*HWTP*TPYPP/(TPTPD*WPY))
  }
```

### Than, you can pass the arguments to get your results

```
fermis_piano_tuner(
  Population = 2695598,
  PPH = 2,
  HWTP = 0.04,
  TPYPP = 2,
  TPTPD = 6,
  WPY = 261
    )
[1] 68.85308
```

### And if you want to pass multiple arguments you can use `pmap`

```
library(purrr)
pmap(
  .l =   tibble::tibble(
    Population  = c(2695598,2679080),
    PPH = c(2,2.48),
    HWTP = c(0.04,0.04),
    TPYPP = c(2,2), 
    TPTPD= c(6,6), 
    WPY = c(261,261)
  ),
  .f = fermis_piano_tuner
)
[[1]]
[1] 68.85308

[[2]]
[1] 55.18642
```